# String length function gives TypeError: 'str' object is not callable in google colaboratory

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, string-length

I was coding a small project on Google Colaboratory and ran into a problem with the len() function, namely that it wouldn't work. I isolated it down and even this bit of code wont work:

`string = "Hello world" 
print(len(string))`

It gives me this error:

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

I've copied and pasted it over into a coding block on a tutorial website, and sure enough, it has no problem whatsoever.

Edit: Okay last night I gave up and went to bed, this morning I showed the error to a friend AND NOW IT WORKS. I didn't touch the bloody code and it just solved itself. I'm mad. Anyways, thanks for the help.

Comment: You have probably tried to call a string object like string() because this error happens in this cases

Answer (score 1):

you probably have a class that has a method and a string property of the same name -- (in your case len), you trying to call the string property that gives you length of the string but actually the len method defined in the class you created is being called . Also make sure you dont have a variable called str in your code.

Comment: Exactly. Restarting the runtime in google colab solved it for me